# How to read rows from Columns in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rows

I am working on a small project for converting students data to intervals. The program simply reads the data, and selects the marks (integer) from the marks columns, to convert them to intervals after sorting them in ascending order. Any one can help me with this particular part, with many thanks:

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row


case class Rating(mark: Int, classes: String, schooles: String, name: String)

val Result = sc.textFile("hdfs://schools:9000/input/marks.csv").map(_.split(",")).map(p => Rating(p(0).toInt, p(1).trim, p(2).trim, p(3).trim)).toDF
val all_marks = Result.groupBy("classes", "schooles","name").agg(collect_list("mark") as "marks",count("*") as "cnt").where($"cnt" > 10)

val mrk=all_marks.select("marks")
```

The part I need help with:

```
mrk.foreach(
    var ascending=mrk.sort
    var interval=ascending[0]+"-"+ascending[ascending.size]
)
```

How can I read the marks row by row, so I can sort them, and convert them to an interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a user defined functions to create a new field as a interval from your list

Here is a simple example as you have already calculated the column marks

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ddf1 = Seq(List(2,3,1), List(6,4,3)).toDF("marks")

val testUdf = udf((list: Seq[Int]) => {
  val ascending = list.sorted  //sorts in ascending order 
  s"${ascending(0)} - ${ascending(ascending.size - 1)}"
})

ddf1.withColumn("marks", testUdf($"marks"))
```

Output:

```
+-----+
|marks|
+-----+
|1 - 3|
|3 - 6|
+-----+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanks Shankar, but how to convert the dataframe "val mrk=all_marks.select("marks")" to Seq and List of "val ddf1 = Seq(List(2,3,1), List(6,4,3)).toDF("marks")"

Comment: Why do you want to convert to list ? I think that is not the good idea

Comment: If you really want mrk.rdd.map(r=> r(0)).collect() this is how you can do

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use a next way to get the such result - convert data frame to RDD with List type, apply map function and convert RDD back to data frame:

```
mrk.rdd.map(_.getList[Int](0).toList).map(l => s"${l.min} - ${l.max}").toDF("marks")
```

Note: `getList[Int]` returns Java's `utils.List` type and to convert it into Scala's List we have to use `toList` method and import `scala.collection.JavaConversions._`.

Also may be used DataSet API instead of RDD:

```
mrk.map(_.getList[Int](0).toList).map(l => s"${l.min} - ${l.max}").toDF("marks")
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use a WrappedArray to get the UDF working, like this:

```
case class Rating(mark: Int, classes: String, schooles: String, name: String)

val Result = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Rating(56, "classA", "SchoolA", "English"),
  Rating(57, "classB", "SchoolA", "English"),
  Rating(58, "classA", "SchoolA", "English"),
  Rating(59, "classB", "SchoolA", "English"),
  Rating(60, "classA", "SchoolA", "English"),
  Rating(61, "classA", "SchoolA", "English"))).toDF()


val toInterval = udf((marks: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]) => s"${marks.min}-${marks.max}")

val all_marks = Result.groupBy("classes", "schooles","name").agg(collect_list("mark") as "marks",count("*") as "cnt")

all_marks.select("marks").withColumn("interval", toInterval(col("marks"))).show()
```

Output:

```
+----------------+--------+
|           marks|interval|
+----------------+--------+
|[56, 58, 60, 61]|   56-61|
|        [57, 59]|   57-59|
+----------------+--------+
```